# Recognize an Update plugin is caused by a change in a Detail record

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a plugin step registered as follows:

- Sandbox, Database
- Update message
- Quote entity
- Post Operation (stage 40)
- Synchronous execution, Online only

The main method is simply

```
public void Execute()
{
    throw new ArgumentException("DEBUG HALT");
}
```

The goal of the plugin will be to change a field in the `Opportunity` from which the quote was originated (I'm going to retrieve it, change the field, and update it).

When saving the quote (`OnSave` event), I already have some scripts which handle the Quote Details:

- Delete all quote details (via OData)
- Read quote details data from an external source
- Re-create the quote details (via OData)

(The whole process involving the Quote Details I believe is not relevant, it works perfectly anyway)

*Now, when I click "Save" on the Quote, the plugin is fired **many times**, not only once. I see that my OData steps fail and show the exception message of this plugin...*

I inspected the `ParentContext` to check out what was happening, I see that

```
PrimaryEntityName = "quote"
MessageName = "Retrieve"
```

I expected to have something to do with the `quotedetail` entity ? I most definitely don't want to execute the step more than once per quote operation: this step is going to be registered on other messages too (Create, Delete, Close, SetState) and I'd very much like for it to *not* repeat itself: is what I'm after even reasonable ? How do I distinguish how/why the plugin fired ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can look at to inspect the plugin context to determined what is happening.  In your case if you're going to register the plugin against different entities you'll want to inspected the `Context.PrimaryEntityName`, `Context.MessageName`, and `Context.Depth` to determine if this is the message you're interested in.  The `PrimaryEntityName` and `MessageName` are self explanatory.  The `Context.Depth` will tell you [how many plugins have fired that caused this plugin to fire](http://chaitanyaprasadtk.blogspot.com/2011/11/contextdepth-in-plugin.html).

[Be careful when using depth:](http://roscode.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/crm-2011-plugins-avoiding-infinite-loops/)

> You must be careful when using the Depth property as there are more
>   complex scenarios that you may run into. For example, a data import
>   may trigger a workflow to update the “Full Name” of a Member, which in
>   turn will execute our plugin. In this case, the Depth will be 3 at the
>   first execution of the plugin. If you left the code snippet above
>   unchanged, the plugin logic will never get executed.

[And another link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106926/microsoft-crm-plugin-infinite-loop/18110030#18110030)

As long as you understand all of your plugins that are triggering each other, plugin parameters may be a better bet.

Comment: Unfortunately `Depth` is always 1 (I sort of expected this, there is only one plugin step involved), I'm going to look more closely at the parent context in hope *something* changes

Comment: If the `Depth` is `1`, then something performed the exact thing that the plugin said happened.  The `Context.PrimaryEntityName` and `Context.MessageName` will contain the trigger that caused the plugin to fire.  It will be caused either via the Ui, or the SDK.